# jQuery Validate property 'max' isn't working on my input field

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have an input that I want to set the max value to 255. I'm not submitting the form, but rather calling a function which submits the data via ajax.

Some of the other validate checks are working, like required and digits, but max isn't working. I'm using jQuery 1.4.4 and validate 1.7.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" maxlength="3" style=" width: 190px" value="" name="Repeats" id="formfield_Repeats">
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#my_form").validate({
      rules: {
         formfield_Repeats: {
            digits: true,
            required: true,
            max: 255
         }
      }
   });
});
```

When I go to save the app I call the `valid()` method on the form.

Is it a version mismatch with jQuery and the validate plugin? I could upgrade both, but the project is HUGE and I don't necessarily want to have to retest the entire app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jquery validate uses the NAMES of inputs, not the id's  so you should have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#my_form").validate({
      rules: {
         Repeats: {
            digits: true,
            required: true,
            max: 255
         }
      }
   });
});
```

EDIT: 
hmm, ok, let's try adding the rule directly to the input field:

```
$("#my_form").validate();

$('#formfield_Repeats').rules('add', {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    max: 255
});
```

EDIT: 
have a look at this js fiddle:  it shows this working exactly as expected with validate 1.7 and jquery 1.4.4
http://jsfiddle.net/Et9vM/

Comment: ditto @Patricia, who beat me to the response.

Comment: I tried changing the field to Repeats and that still didn't seem to work. The other fields on the form seem to have their class set manually like class="required" and they work. Is there a way to add the max value check using classes? Something like max255?

Comment: hmm, does any of the validation fire? if it's empty does it allow it to post?

Comment: Yes, when I just run the javascript code above it will allow me to submit without a have in Repeats. If I add the "required" class in the ASPX file it won't let me submit without a value. It's a custom input control that we've written and that may be part of the problem, but the js and validate calls look like they should work.

Comment: hmm, ok, see my edit.  this kind of approach has worked for me (and a couple other ppl i've helped with validate acting weird).

Comment: OK, that seemed to have helped. Required and digits are now being checked, but max still isn't. Are my validate plugin and jquery version incompatible with the 'max' check?

Comment: hmmm
max has been in jquery validate for a long time, i've got 1.6 and it's in there, so i don't think that's it.

Comment: have a look at the js fiddle i just made, it uses jquery 1.4.4 and jquery validate 1.7, which is your set up, and it works.  must be something else on your page interfering

Comment: Thanks Patricia! Your code DID work for me once I realized that .load() was being used to get the dialog where my form was. So the problem wasn't the code not working it was that the code was being called on a form that didn't exist yet :s

Comment: that'll do it!  put it in the callback for the load and your good to go!

Answer (score 0):

hi it should maxlength instead of max... Just go through this [Link for maxlength validation jquery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/maxlength)

Hop this helps

Comment: Yes I have maxlength set to 3 (3 digits), but they could enter 500. The data type in the DB is tinyint so 255 max value.